# http client exception handling in asp.net core

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

i am using .net 5 latest prview..Below is the code for  http client in mvc

```
var response = await _httpClient.SendAsync(request);
         try
        { 
            response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();
            data = await response.Content.ReadFromJsonAsync<Abc>();
            return data;
        }
        catch (HttpRequestException ex) when (ex.StatusCode = 404)  ----how to check 404 error?
        {
            throw;
        }
        catch (HttpRequestException ex) when (ex.StatusCode == 503)
        {
            throw;
        }
```

How to check 404 error or other details in catch.am getting below error.Thanks in advance...

[image]

Comment: No..i removed also it showing another error

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The easiest way would be to use the proper enum for comparison:

```
var response = await _httpClient.SendAsync(request);
try
{ 
    response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();
    data = await response.Content.ReadFromJsonAsync<Abc>();
    return data;
}
catch (HttpRequestException ex) when (ex.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.NotFound)  ----how to check 404 error?
{
    throw;
}
catch (HttpRequestException ex) when (ex.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.ServiceUnavailable)
{
    throw;
}
```

Another option would be casting to (int?), but using the enum should provide better readibility.

Answer (score 6):

[HttpRequestException.StatusCode](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.http.httprequestexception.statuscode?view=net-5.0#System_Net_Http_HttpRequestException_StatusCode) is type of [HttpStatusCode](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.httpstatuscode?view=net-5.0). You can't compare directly with int.

You can cast the status code to int like :

```cs
try
{ 
    response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();
    data = await response.Content.ReadFromJsonAsync<Abc>();
    return data;
}
catch (HttpRequestException ex) when (((int)ex.StatusCode) == 404)
{
    throw;
}
catch (HttpRequestException ex) when (((int)ex.StatusCode) == 503)
{
    throw;
}
```

Or compare with the enumeration's values :

```cs
try
{ 
    response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();
    data = await response.Content.ReadFromJsonAsync<Abc>();
    return data;
}
catch (HttpRequestException ex) when (ex.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.NotFound)
{
    throw;
}
catch (HttpRequestException ex) when (ex.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.ServiceUnavailable)
{
    throw;
}
```