# In c# .net how to handle if third party Rest API returns 500/400 status code with data/response

Tags: .net, exception, http-status-codes

When I calling Third party Rest API in some scenario they are sending response with HTTP status code 500/404. How I can handle like this scenario.
Should I catch web exception and then check the status code?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63646678/http-client-exception-handling-in-asp-net-core

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.